# How to create and related multiple node to another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Imagine these classes in C#:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string[] HashTags { get; set; }
}
```

each user can add a post and the relation between them would be the Author, each post could have an array of hash-tags which each of them is going to be a separate node in graph.

when i am going to save each post, I would find the user in grph, create a post node and relate them with a Author Relationship.

the Question is how can I create and relate each hashTag to the post in the same query. (to be inside a transaction).

How could I dynamically add item to query to create it.
the problem is that it could not create node and the relation in one line of create.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var cypherQuery = Db.Instance.Cypher
                .Match("(user:User)")
                .Where((User user) => user.Username == "XYZ")

                .Create("user-[:Author]->(post:Post {newPost})")
                .WithParam("newPost", new Post() {Id = 1, Text = "Here is my post about #someHashTag"});
                 //How to relate this node to the number of hashTags in Post Object???
                cypherQuery.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

is it good to be in single query or should i divide it in multiple round trips.

I Have tried something with foeach but it seams that the post does not have any value inside the foreach loop:

I have tried something like this:

```
var cypherCommand = Db.Instance.Cypher
                .Match("(user:User)")
                .Where((User user) => user.Username == "farvashani")

                .Create("user-[:Author]->(post:Post {newPost})")
                .WithParam("newPost", "here is my post about @Tag1 and Tag2")
                .ForEach(@"(hashtag in {hashTags}|
                            MERGE post-[:Mentioned]->(hash:HashTag {Text: hashtag}))")
                .WithParam("hashTags", new string[] {"Tag1", "Tag2"});
                cypherCommand.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, i think you have to pre-process the Text property first.

```
 String text = ""Here is my post about #someHashTag""; // For example
 List<String> hashTags = new List<String>();
 int cnt = 0;
 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\w)#\w+"))
    {
        hashTags.Add(match.Value);
    }
```

Then create new instance of Post:

```
Post newPost = new Post
        {
            Id = 1,
            Text = "Here is my post about #someHashTag",
            hashTags = hashTags
        };
```

So, you can use this Cypher:

```
var cypherCommand = Db.Instance.Cypher
            .Match("(user:User)")
            .Where((User user) => user.Username == "farvashani")

            .Create("user-[:Author]->(post:Post {newPost})")
            .WithParam(new {newPost}).ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Hope this help.

P/s: Could I ask you a question? Do you think it is better for you to retrieve the separated graph if you use each hashTag as a label of Post? newPost:someHashTag for example?